# In a javascript object, how to sum values from one field if a tag exists in another field?

Tags: javascript

If the data is like: -

```json
const dis ={
    "data":[
        {
            "Hazard_type": ["Tornado","Hurricane"],
            "County": "Anderson",
            "State": "TX",
            "FIPS_code": 48001,
            "Longitude": -95.687072,
            "Latitude": 31.776143,
            "Property_Damage": 10000000,
            "Crop_Damage": 0
        },
        {
            "Hazard_type": ["Hurricane"],
            "County": "Anderson",
            "State": "TX",
            "FIPS_code": 48001,
            "Longitude": -95.687072,
            "Latitude": 31.776143,
            "Property_Damage": 4914933.84,
            "Crop_Damage": 0
        },
    ]
}
```

And I want to create another json array which has aggregate damage per unique tag in the Hazard type. What should be the approach here? (Very new to Javascript)

Comment: FYI, JSON is not relevant to this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's one way you might accomplish the task, making use of [Array.filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) and [Array.reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce).

Note that I changed the values of Crop_Damage from zeros to 3 and 1, to make it more evident the code works.

```js
const dis ={
    "data":[
        {
            "Hazard_type": ["Tornado","Hurricane"],
            "County": "Anderson",
            "State": "TX",
            "FIPS_code": 48001,
            "Longitude": -95.687072,
            "Latitude": 31.776143,
            "Property_Damage": 10000000,
            "Crop_Damage": 1
        },
        {
            "Hazard_type": ["Hurricane"],
            "County": "Anderson",
            "State": "TX",
            "FIPS_code": 48001,
            "Longitude": -95.687072,
            "Latitude": 31.776143,
            "Property_Damage": 4914933.84,
            "Crop_Damage": 3
        },
    ]
};

const removeDuplicates = (key, index, array) => {
  return array.lastIndexOf(key) === index;
};

const distinctHazards = dis.data.map(row => row.Hazard_type).flat().filter(removeDuplicates);

/*
 * Array.filter() ensures we only examine the subset of the array having to do with one Hazard at a time
 * Array.reduce() is an accumulator that simply sums the fields (Crop_Damage) up. 
*/
const scores = distinctHazards.map(hazard => {
    const damages = dis.data.filter(row => {
        return row.Hazard_type.includes(hazard);
    });
    return {hazard, damages: damages.map(row => row.Crop_Damage).reduce((a,b) => {
        return Number(a) + Number(b);
    })};
});

console.log(scores);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Array.map function. See the definition for this function [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map):

For example, you can use it for:

```
const rows = [
  { name: "Name 1", price: 1.0, tax, 0.5 }, 
  { name: "Name 2"price: 2.0, tax, 0.5 }
];
const newRows = rows.map(row => {
   return {
      ..row,
      totalPrice: row.price + tax,
   };
});
```

So after of this newRows is like:

```
[
  { name: "Name 1", price: 1.0, tax, 0.5, totalPrice: 1.5 }, 
  { name: "Name 2"price: 2.0, tax, 0.5, totalPrice: 2.5 }
]
```

Comment: The main problem I am facing is the tags aren't unique per object but repeating. As you can see in the example, Hurricane is in both the objects. So when I get Hurricane as type, the damage should have an aggregate of the damages.

Comment: You can use and if sentence to check another conditions